# Trouble passing compatibility test on Windows. Video card meets requirements but still fails?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, mac, virtual-machine, compatibility

I am having a rough time getting my computer to pass the compatibility test, even though it seems to meet all the requirements. I have 512 MB of dedicated video memory (the minimum), but I still fail the test. Any suggestions?

[image: screenshot of the failure point]

Comment: This could be a rounding issue, or a bug. Either way, being just at the minimum isn't a great place to be.

Comment: "Parallels Desktop does not control when to switch between graphics cards. This decision is made by macOS." https://kb.parallels.com/122807 Note: your question is not really a GIS related question.